# Telegram Bot cannot unban user

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Function to send a message:

```
 const TOKEN = '99999999:AAAAAAAJjZ_T6hAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
 const URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.TOKEN.'/';

function sendGetRequest($method,$params=null){
    if($params){
        $url = URL.$method.'?'.http_build_query($params);
    }else{
        $url = URL.$method;
    }
    return json_decode(file_get_contents($url), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
}
```

Function call:

```
$un_ban_params = [
            'chat_id'=> $chat_id,
            'user_id'=> $user_id*1,
                 ];

sendGetRequest( 'unbanChatMember', $un_ban_params);
```

The call returns null.
Accordingly, the link to return to the group does not appear.

Comment: Please, explain it more and tell what is your problem exactly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is found. "unbanChatMember" is only valid in supergroups and channels. For a simple group, this method does not work.